# Let's Encrypt changing domain x.com to y.com

Tags: ubuntu, debian, lets-encrypt, certbot

Hi I've installed certbot on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS machine. It is installed on x.com domain and I want to have a certificate for y.com domain, how do I do this?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please check [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: suggest using certbot to get cert for your y.com domain for let's encrypt. 
 https://certbot.eff.org/

Answer (score 0):

suggest using certbot to get cert for your y.com domain for let's encrypt. 
 https://certbot.eff.org/.  [Here's a tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04) for ubuntu 20.04 and apache for let's encrypt that does a good job of explaining

```
sudo certbot --apache
```